# Add a LIKE (fan page) button within a fan page Tab

Tags: tabs, facebook-page

I'm trying to add a LIKE button (for my fan page) within a fan page tab...

Why ? Because the tab displays a contest that will only be available to people who like the page.

You can have a look to the fan page tab [here](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Salon-Babyboom/237448289650901?ref=ts&sk=app_275339329168531)

I use, `parsePageSignedRequest` to check if the user already like the page.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like it's already working.  When I like the Facebook page, it does a refresh and I see the fan only content.  When I unlike the Facebook page, then it reverts me back to the fan-gate.

Comment: Yeah but what I'm trying to achieve is to ADD a big LIKE button into the tab... In order for the user who are not fan yet, to CLICK.

Comment: But why?  What you have is a very good example of a working fan gate.  Why change it?

Comment: I know it works fine... But I wanted to add a LIKE big button into the tab as well. I did it, you can have a look here <http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/838/capturedcran20120126121.png/> or check the fan page.

Comment: Adding a like button is super easy as compared to that fan-gate you made. Just `Copy/Paste` the code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: Of course it is super easy, but finding a way to make it looks like the big "J'aime" button wasn't that easy :-)... Now it is working like I wanted.

Comment: Wow, you did a good job hiding 6 like buttons behind that image!!  I think that might be a violation of Facebook policies though...

Comment: Yeah that what I'm afraid of ! I'm going to ask directly on the facebook dev page just to be sure... If it's not I will post a little update to this thread with a little How-To

Comment: We are unable to offer legal advice.  The only advice I can offer for you to contact your corporate attorney if you think anything you've done could violate any rules.

Comment: The button is gone now from your Facebook page. What happened. Did facebook closed the workaround.